# Make multiple API Post requests using Python

Tags: python, api

I`m looking for a way to send several API post requests at once.

An example of the API request that I have is below:

```
https://xxx.api.xxx.com/Apiv3/json?NetworkToken=XXXXXXXXXX&Target=Offer&Method=create&data[prevention]=disabled&data[session_hours]=100&data[offer_url]=https%www.XXXXXX&data[preview_url]=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ZZZZ&data[name]=Test&data[has_goals_enabled]=1&data[expiration_date]=2050-12-31+00%3A00%3A00&data[description]=XXXXX&data[max_payout]=XXX&data[default_payout]=XX&data[default_goal_name]=XXXX&data[revenue_type]=XXX&data[protocol]=server&data[status]=active&data[advertiser_id]=XXX
```

I have several of similar requests like this where the only difference between them is some of the data after the equal sign

What I have today is possible to do one by one, only using the `r = requests.post('')`
I tried to use the `requests. post(data=setup.txt)` but it did not work. This is the first time I`m doing a similar process so not sure what is the easiest way to tackle this issue

Comment: When you say 'same time' do you mean exactly the same time? Or do you want to automate the process?

Comment: More as automate the process of instead going one by one, run the request for all